# How can I get tight bounds of an svg text element?

Tags: html, svg

I need 'tight' bounds of SVG text elements.  When I use `getBBox`, I get height that seem to include full possible glyph height for a font without regard for the specific characters in my text.  What I get for width varies per browser but generally includes a few units more than the characters actually take up in length. Is there any way to get a box that precisely wraps only the characters in my text?

For example, I want the rect created below to tightly wrap the text '.....'  However, there is a lot of 'leftover' vertical space in the bounding box returned by `getBBox`.  Thanks for any help.  This is my first post to StackOverflow, so I also welcome formatting/question presentation critiques.

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
        <text>.....</text>
        <rect style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,100,100);stroke-width:1"/>
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var layout = function() {
        var numB = $("text").get(0).getBBox();
        $("rect").attr("x", 0);
        $("rect").attr("y", 0);
        $("rect").attr("width", numB.width);
        $("rect").attr("height", numB.height);
        $("text").attr("y", numB.height);
    }
    
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
            layout();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who hits this issue, I may finally have what I wanted from this tool: [Font.js](https://github.com/Pomax/lib-font). I have been able to get pixel-perfect boundaries of single characters and strings in Verdana.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is on-spot, but the answer isn't easy.

If you are using an SVG font you could access the metrics in the font file. It will have the metrics for the descenders, ascenders, baseline, xheight. So you could check if your string has any descenders (jgqp and such), uppercase letters and such. It would still be tricky and not entirely accurate.

The second thing you could try is rendering the same text in canvas and checking the dimensions. I don't know exactly how to do this, it should not be too complicated.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid it would be less than simplistic, but I figured it was worth asking

Comment: For anyone else who hits this issue, I may finally have what I wanted from this tool: [Font.js](http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/Font.js/).  I have been able to get pixel-perfect boundaries of single characters and strings in Verdana.

Comment: Proper StackOverflow etiquette would be to put that comment in an answer, un-accept my answer and accept yours :)

Comment: Do you know if Font.js still the best way today?